# Visual Studio Installer using obfuscated DLL's

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have a C# asp.net Core WPF application. I have a obfuscator that I have included in my main projects publish.

It works by building, then obsfactating and then copying the dll files over the published files.

This how that works:

```
<Target Name="Obfuscation" AfterTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(TargetDir)" Command="obfuscar.console $(ProjectDir)obfuscar.xml" />
    <ItemGroup>
        <DistFiles Include="$(OutDir)Obfuscated\**\*.dll; $(OutDir)Obfuscated\**\*.exe" />
        <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
            <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.RecursiveDir)%(DistFiles.Filename)%(DistFiles.Extension)</RelativePath>
        </ResolvedFileToPublish>
        
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
<Target Name="CopyObfuscation" AfterTargets="Obfuscation" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Exec Command="DEL $(TargetDir)\_obs\Mapping.txt" />
    <Exec Command="MOVE $(TargetDir)\_obs\*.* $(TargetDir)" />
</Target>
```

This works fine.

However I have a visual studio installer project (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2022)

This is set to package the files from the publish.

[image]

there are not a lot of options.

When I build the installer package, it uses the publish profile (Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml)

but it does not run the obsfcacation script (that is in the main project .csproj file)

How can I package the obsfacated files instead?